# How many times is the red wedding prophesied?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

I have recently started re-reading the ***A Song of Ice and Fire*** series and noticed that during *A Clash of Kings* that the Red Wedding is prophesied at least twice.  I first noticed this during Daenerys' visit to the Warlocks of Qarth and again seen in a dream by Theon shortly before his defeat by the Bastard of Bolton.

**My question is does anyone else dream or see this happening prior to the Red Wedding or are these the only instances?**

I know other things are foreshadowed throughout the books but I'm only seeking info on these events.

Comment: Prophecy and foreshadowing are two different things. For example, The Hound says to Arya: `"I'm sick of it. Keep your mouth shut and do as I tell you, and maybe we'll even be in time for your uncle's bloody wedding."`. Some take that as foreshadowing, yet it wasn't a prophecy *per se*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There may be more than these...but there are quite a few that I've caught

1. Jon's crypt dream.  Less clear if it specifically indicates RW but there's a feast going on and he knows everyone at the Feast is dead.
2. House of the Undying
3. Theon's dream
4. The Ghost of Highheart quite accurately predicts the wedding down to several minute details.
5. Patchface's Rhyme "Fool’s blood. King’s blood, blood on the maiden’s thigh, but chains for the guests and chains for the bridegroom, aye, aye, aye"

Comment: The Ghost of Highheart also tells Thoros of Myr to "look into his fires", where he later presumably saw the Red Wedding.